# SWT ControlDecoration goes behing adjacent control

Tags: swt

As you see in the attached screenshot, I have two adjacent SWT buttons which can show a **decoration** (a `ControlDecoration` object).

When I activate the decoration, it gets partially hidden by the adjacent button: is there a way I can keep the layout spacing tight and show the decoration on the top of the layers stack?

[image]

Comment: Yes. Post your code. We can choose the position of overlay icon.

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK : any comment about the answer by @greg-449?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaDoc for `ControlDecoration` says:

> ControlDecoration renders the image adjacent to the specified (already
>   created) control, with no guarantee that it won't be clipped or
>   otherwise obscured or overlapped by adjacent controls, including
>   another ControlDecoration placed in the same location. Clients should
>   ensure that there is adequate space adjacent to the control to show
>   the decoration properly.

So, No, there is no way to get this show on top of controls.

Comment: Can't we use SWT.TOP | SWT.LEFT to position it top-left or SWT.BOTTOM | SWT.LEFT to place bottom-left style bit for ControlDecoration?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Yes but that still requires you to leave space in the margins of the layout around the control

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK Note that decorations always appear on either the left or right side of the control, never above or below it. SWT.TOP | SWT.LEFT means the top part of the left hand margin.

Answer (score 1):

If your Button is showing an image, you could use label decorations (class LabelDecorator) to create a composie image that is the result of the button image and the small image in the top right corner.